# Parse unexpected symbol error in function applied over list

Tags: r

I'm trying to check the "pin" numbers of cases with missing data for each variable of interest in my dataset.

Here are some fake data:

```
c <- data.frame(pin = c(1, 2, 3, 4), type = c(1, 1, 2, 2), v1 = c(1, NA, NA, 
NA), v2 = c(NA, NA, 1, 1))
```

I wrote a function "m.pin" to do this:

```
m.pin <- function(x, data = "c", return = "$pin") {
  sect <- gsub("^.*\\[", "\\[", deparse(substitute(x)))
  vect <- eval(parse(text = paste(data, return, sect, sep = "")))
  return(vect[is.na(x)])
}
```

And I use it like so:

```
m.pin(c$v1[c$type == 1])
[1] 2
```

I wrote a function to apply "m.pin" over a list of variables to only return pins with missing data:

```
return.m.pin <- function(x, fun = m.pin) {
  val.list <- lapply(x, fun)
  condition <- lapply(val.list, function(x) length(x) > 0)
  val.list[unlist(condition)]
}
```

But when I apply it, I get this error:

```
l <- lst(c$v1[c$type == 1], c$v2[c$type == 2])
return.m.pin(l) 
Error in parse(text = paste(data, return, sect, sep = "")) :
  <text>:1:9: unexpected ']'
1: c$pin[i]]
            ^
```

How can I rewrite my function(s) to avoid this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: Simple answer is (a) don't use `eval`, (b) don't use `parse`, (c) don't use `deparse`, (d) don't use `substitute`. With a side note of (e) don't use `c` as a variable name because it's the name of the most common R function. It's like naming a person "The".

Comment: Can you describe your goal in words? And maybe show your desired output for the "apply over a list" version? I *think* you are looking to find which `pin` values are associated with `NA` values for a specific `v_i` column and a specific values of the `type` column. Is this right?

Comment: When you `lapply` your function, the `paste()` is creating something like `df$pinx[[1]]` and hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

Please see Gregor's comment for the most critical issues with your code (to add: don't use `return` as a variable name as it is the name of a base R function).

It's not clear to me why you want to define a specific function `m.pin`, nor what you ultimately are trying to do, but I am assuming this is a critical design component.

Rewriting `m.pin` as

```
m.pin <- function(df, type, vcol) which(df[, "type"] == type & is.na(df[, vcol]))
```

we get

```
m.pin(df, 1, "v1")
#[1] 2
```

Or to identify rows with `NA` in `"v1"` for all `type`s

```
lapply(unique(df$type), function(x) m.pin(df, x, "v1"))
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4
```

---

### Update

In response to Gregor's comment, perhaps this is what you're after?

```
by(df, df$type, function(x)
    list(v1 = x$pin[which(is.na(x$v1))], v2 = x$pin[which(is.na(x$v2))]))
#    df$type: 1
#    $v1
#    [1] 2
#
#    $v2
#    [1] 1 2
#
#    ------------------------------------------------------------
#    df$type: 2
#    $v1
#    [1] 3 4
#
#    $v2
#    integer(0)
```

This returns a `list` of the `pin` numbers for every `type` and `NA` entries in `v1`/`v2`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(
    pin = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
    type = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
    v1 = c(1, NA, NA, NA), 
    v2 = c(NA, NA, 1, 1))
```

Comment: @Gregor Ah yes, you're right. I made an edit with an updated solution using `by`. I'm a bit in the dark of what OP wants to do. Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: 100% agree on XY.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rewriting like this (if this approach is to be taken at all). I call your data `d` because `c` is already the name of an extremely common function.

```
# string column names, pass in the data frame as an object
# means no need for eval, parse, substitute, etc.
foo = function(data, na_col, return_col = "pin", filter_col, filter_val) {
  if(! missing(filter_col) & ! missing(filter_val)) {
    data = data[data[, filter_col] == filter_val, ]
  }  
  data[is.na(data[, na_col]), return_col]
}

# working on the whole data frame
foo(d, na_col = "v1", return_col = "pin")
# [1] 2 3 4

# passing in a subset of the data
foo(d[d$type == 1, ], "v1", "pin")
# [1] 2

# using function arguments to subset the data
foo(d, "v1", "pin", filter_col = "type", filter_val = 1)
# [1] 2


# calling it with changing arguments:
# you could use `Map` or `mapply` to be fancy, but this for loop is nice and clear
inputs = data.frame(na_col = c("v1", "v2"), filter_val = c(1, 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
result = list()
for (i in 1:nrow(inputs)) {
  result[[i]] = foo(d, na_col = inputs$na_col[i], return_col = "pin",
                    filter_col = "type", filter_val = inputs$filter_val[i])
}
result
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# numeric(0)
```

---

A different approach I would suggest is melting your data into a long format, and simply taking a subset of the `NA` values, hence getting all combinations of `type` and the `v*` columns that have `NA` values at once. Do this once, and no function is needed to look up individual combinations.

```
d_long = reshape2::melt(d, id.vars = c("pin", "type"))

library(dplyr)
d_long %>% filter(is.na(value)) %>%
  arrange(variable, type)
#   pin type variable value
# 1   2    1       v1    NA
# 2   3    2       v1    NA
# 3   4    2       v1    NA
# 4   1    1       v2    NA
# 5   2    1       v2    NA
```